# What is the name of this onion like plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, flowers, wildflowers

[image]

### Hello

About an year ago, I found this plant in the streets. I couldn't let it die there, so I took it my home. What is its name so that I can take care of it?

I searched the Internet with no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is pregnant onion, Albuca bracteata.